# How do i combine multiple fields from a view into one hyperlink?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Im sorta stuck on an issue. I have one view where i am displaying 5 fields under an image. These fields are all clickable links or I have explicitly declared them as links.The problem:

I need to combine each field/link into one link. I tried the "Combine Filter" but when i try to combine 3 of the 5 fields i have exposed. the whole view disappears from the preview screen in the View screen.

Is there's something that i could do leveraging drupal or should i use jquery/JavaScript to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you said *how* you wanted combine them, so I will assume it is similar to the same way I often do.
Views has two checkboxes that you will want to use for this.  1 is the Exclude from Display at the top of the field setting, and 2 is the Rewrite Results > Rewrite the output of this field.

Assuming one field is the the path, two are taxonomy or something, one is the words you want for the link, etc...  Either pick the one that links directly where you want it, set it as the last field of the five, and exclude it.  Or it does not really matter what order, and just exclude the first four fields of the five.  What Exclude does is tell the view to fetch the value, make the token available for you, and not impact the display.

Then in the fifth field you use that Rewrite option.  A textbox will appear and below it is the list of available tokens to use.  Then you construct the one link that you want composed of the five fields:

```
`<a href="[field_path]" class="[field_taxononmy] custom" title="[field_example]" >[field_taxonomy] [field_words]</a>`
```

As they say in the #drupal-support irc, more details will get you a better answer.

Comment: This was spot on. Thanks DeveloperWeeks!